# Set shipping address issue with shipping.js : M2

Tags: magento2, shipping, shipping-address

> {"message":"Error occurred during \"shipping_address\" processing.
>   Error occurred during \"street\" processing. Invalid type for value:
>   \"string\". Expected Type: \"string[]\".","trace":null}

Getting above error when i'm trying to set shipping address in `shipping.js` file.

shipping.js

```
setShippingInformation: function () {

                    //alert('trtrt'); 
                        var shippingAddress = quote.shippingAddress();
                        shippingAddress.firstname = 'gggg';//$('[name="pickup_name"]').val();
                        shippingAddress.lastname  = 'hhhhh';//$('[name="pickup_lastname"]').val();
                        shippingAddress.street    = 'Abcd street';//new Array(place.street);
                        shippingAddress.city      = 'Los Angeles';//place.city;
                        shippingAddress.countryId = 'US';//place.country_id;
                        shippingAddress.telephone = '1234512345'; //+place.telephone;
                        shippingAddress.region  = "illionis";
                        shippingAddress.regionId  = "12";
                        shippingAddress.postcode  = '45454';//place.postcode;

                        selectShippingAddress(shippingAddress);
                        quote.shippingMethod('mpcustomshipping');

                        selectShippingMethodAction('mpcustomshipping');


                        setShippingInformationAction().done(
                                function () {
                                    stepNavigator.next();
                                }
                        ); 
            },
```

rest/default/V1/guest-carts/f3fea8d0bef3344599bfc3467da43139/shipping-information

```
<response>
<message>Request does not match any route.</message>
<trace/>
</response>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`shippingAddress.street` is an array and you are passing to the string that's why it gives the error, Try to pass the value as an array `shippingAddress.street = ['Abcd street']`

[image]

Comment: now it gives this error: "message":"Carrier with such method not found: %1, %2","parameters":[null,null],

Comment: This means that It will resolve the error which you posted in question and now you have a different error, please check you have `mpcustomshipping` shipping method is enabled or not and you have this shipping method or not

Comment: yes, i have approved your answer